# maven-site-plugin skip skip report for some module

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

There is a project:

```
-parent
-parent-pom.xml
-moduleA
--a-pom.xml
-moduleB
--b-pom.xml
```

There is a plugin in `parent-pom.xml`.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
```

I need to skip the report in `moduleB`. I added this to `b-pom.xml`

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Can I skip `moduleB` from report in `parent-pom.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot skip `moduleB` in the report from the parent POM unless you are willing to touch the POM of `moduleB`.

Otherwise this is impossible.